# Insetting smaller image inside a larger one using ImageMagick

Tags: bash, imagemagick

How would one go about insetting a smaller image inside a larger one?

I have two images as shown below:

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

The first image needs to go into the topleft corner of the second one. Its width is almost one tenth the width of the second one. I tried a number of things like compositing, and repage and merging layers, but I can't seem to get the hang of it yet. I am very new to imagemagick, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not certain what you mean exactly but this should give you an idea:

```
convert image1.png -bordercolor black -border 5 image2.png +swap -geometry +50+100 -composite result.png
```

[image]

I loaded the inset picture first and put a 5 pixel border around it, then loaded the background image, swapped them so the background was at the back and composited over the top.

I could, equally, have loaded the background image first, then loaded the inset image in some *"aside-processing"* and then composited the result on top:

```
convert image2.png \( image1.png -bordercolor black -border 5 \) -geometry +50+100 -composite result.png
```

---

I guess with the first method it looks kind of back-to-front and there is a `+swap` in there. With the second method, you have the "complexity" of the parentheses which make sure the border is only applied to the inset image and not the background image.

Comment: Yes thank you, this is almost what I wanted. I get the idea. I think I can work from here.